# Draggable Slider Component In FLEX 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have to use Draggable Slider component in my application.

I have found one [Link](http://dougmccune.com/blog/2007/01/21/draggable-slider-component-for-flex/) but it is not working in FLEX 3.0 Application. I have applied thumbUpSkin, thumbDownSkin, thumbOverSkin, thumbDisabledSkin to my custom Draggable Slider Component still i can't get the slider what i want because this component is working for FLEX 2.0

I want the perfect one that is look on the link given above. Please Help me or give me another component similar as Draggable Slider component

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved that my self.

Please visit this [Link](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/).

Here is the solution for that.. by this link you can get that component compatible with FLEX 3 and even with FLEX 4. you just need to download the zip file which is compatible with your system requirement and you can get many more components with it.

Have a Nice Day.